# $a\notin X' \Rightarrow $ all real number L would be limit of (x) when $x$ tends to $a$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $a$ is not an accumulation point of X, why all real number L would be limit of (x) when $x$ tends to $a$? The book that I am using for real analysis states this with an explanation that I don't get.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is subtle. Suppose $a \notin X'.$ Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $N_\delta(a)\cap X\backslash \{a\}=\emptyset.$ We can use this fact to show that any $L$ satisfies the limit. Let $\epsilon>0$. By the same $\delta$ as above, whenever $x\in N_\delta(a)\cap X\backslash \{a\}$ (which never happens), it is vacuously true that $|x-L|<\epsilon$.

I wouldn't read into this too much as meaning a whole lot. It just means for a limit to occur, there has to be a notion of approaching. My guess is they threw this in to point out several subtleties regarding limits:

1) $\lim_{x\to a} x$ never cares about what's happening at $x=a$. This generates confusion because in calculus classes, we take for granted that often the functions are continuous so we just "plug in." Notice in the above analysis, if we allow $x=a$, then it's certainly not true that $|a-L|<\epsilon$ for any arbitrary $\epsilon$.

2) It shows that removeable points can be arbitrarily assigned, especially in integrals.